# jquery update textbox value while typing on another textbox

Tags: jquery, keyup

I have 2 textbox fields. Email and Username. When i type into the email field I want the username to be update live dynamically, letter for letter by the email field. I have this code but it's not working

```
$('#txt_email').keyup(function() {
                $('#txt_username').text($(this).val());
            });
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j7ECW/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change:

```
$('#txt_username').text($(this).val());
```

to:

```
$('#txt_username').val($(this).val());
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/j7ECW/1/)**